# Significance testing for correlations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, inference

Say I have a set of predictions $X$ which predict some variable $Y$. The correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is $r$. How can I determine if $r$ is significant?

My intuition would be to do a monte carlo type simulation by sampling many random permutations of $X$, computing their correlation with $Y$, and then seeing where my observed correlation $r$ lies in this distribution. Is that method flawed?

Comment: Is this different from regression?

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's just like regression. In that case, to test if the regression coefficient is significantly zero, I'd do a t-test. But how is this different to monte-carlo-ing as above?

Comment: Sounds like you are describing a bootstrapping procedure for calculating a p-value. That is valid and can be useful in some situations. But it's overkill for many simple regression fits because you'll get the same result as a standard p-value.